# VB6 _Validation event not firing when tabbing to Cancel button with CausesValidation = False

Tags: vb6

I have a situation similar to the following simplified description:

A form with a TextBox (call it **txtQty**) in which a user can enter an integer. The event **txtQty_Validate** is used to validate the user input and force them to correct any errors before changing focus. This works great with all other controls on the form except for said **txtQty**. I assume that this is because the **Cancel** button on the form has the property **CausesValidation** necessarily set to false; thus when the user Tabs from **txtQty** to the **Cancel** button (whose **TabIndex** is next) it does not appropriately trigger the **txtQty_Validation** event.

My first instinct was to simply go to the **txtQty_KeyPress** event (which I am already using to make the **RETURN** key behave as **TAB** key) and capture the **TAB** key and temporarily toggle the **CausesValidation** property to allow the **txtQty_Validation** event to fire. However, it seems as though capturing the **TAB** key is not as easy as I had thought it would be.

Any suggestions? I assume that this cannot be the first time anybody creating a Form has come across such a situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this in the Cancel `GotFocus` event.

```
Dim b As Boolean

Call txtQty_Validate(b)
If b Then txtQty.SetFocus
```

Assuming you have something like this

```
Private Sub txtQty_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(txtQty.Text) Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of `CausesValidation = False` on the `Cancel` button. Now when the user enters gibberish in `txtQty` it cannot cancel the form! This is simply beyond annoying. . . User: _Yes, I know quantity is not numeric but I don't care as I'd like to cancel the form and undo whatever I just entered! Please let me go!_